# sed script that replaces a double quoted macro argument string with just the string

Tags: regex, sed

I want to remove the double quotation marks in macro calls using sed (hundreds of files and thousands of occurrences need to be changed).

for example:

```
MY_MACRO("any_string");
```

should be changed to:

```
MY_MACRO(any_string);
```

Note that "any_string" is just an example. It could be just any string (the strings will not contain any space characters though).

I've tried:

```
sed -i '/MY_MACRO(/ s/\"//g' file.c
```

but that may remove `"`:s that shouldn't be removed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i '/MY_MACRO(/ s/("\([^"]*\)")/(\1)/g' file.c
```

Here,

- `/MY_MACRO(/` - matches lines that contain `MY_MACRO(` substring and then
- `s/("\([^"]*\)")/(\1)/g` - searches for `("`, then zero or more chars other than `"` (captured into Group 1) and then `")` and replaces with `(` + Group 1 value + `)`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/5u0N2e).